# PDO prepared statements keep giving my boolean type error when preparing string

Tags: php, json, pdo, postgresql-12

I need help with my PDO prepared statements.

I know my code is not sanitized and is probably open to a lot of hell, but first I need to overcome this error before I can move on to sanitize my code.

I am trying to write a prepared statement with the `WHERE` clause, and somehow it keeps giving me an error that I am using a string for a type boolean. But what boolean??

I added a few vardumps before the error. It is in the counting part of my code.

After which, I would also take some pointers on how to make prepared statements out of user input.

I know, it is dangerous, but perhaps I can sanitize all the inner_join, outer_join etc into allowed table names using a in_array after a database table and column name check.

The reason I need to allow this user input is that I am making a website where people can make their own queries to the database and retrieve whatever info they need. But they should only be able to **SELECT**. Not **UPDATE** or **DROP**!

```
<?php

// Select existing

require_once('ajaxDBQuery.php');

if(!isset($included)) {
    $_GET = json_decode($_GET["json"], true);
} else {
    $_GET = json_decode($json, true);
}

class GET extends ajaxDBQuery
{

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct($_GET['db']);

        // ------------------------------------------------
        $page = 0;
        if (isset($_GET['offset']) && !empty($_GET['offset'])) {
        $page = filter_var($_GET['offset'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        }
        $per_page = 20;
        if (isset($_GET['limit']) && !empty($_GET['limit'])) {
            $per_page = filter_var($_GET['limit'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        }

        if(isset($_GET['where']) && !empty($_GET['where'])) {
            $sqlcount = "SELECT count(*) AS total_records FROM {$_GET['from']['table']} WHERE :test";
            $statement = $this->conn->prepare($sqlcount);

            var_dump($sqlcount);
            var_dump($statement);
            var_dump($_GET['where']);

            $statement->bindParam(':test', $_GET['where'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $statement->execute();
        } else {
            $sqlcount = "SELECT count(*) AS total_records FROM {$_GET['from']['table']}";
            $statement = $this->conn->prepare($sqlcount);
            $statement->execute();
        }

        $row = $statement->fetch();
        $total_records = $row['total_records'];
    
        $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $per_page);
    
        $offset = ($page) * $per_page;
        // ------------------------------------------------
        $sql = "SELECT ";
        for($i = 0; $i < count($_GET['select']['columns']); $i++) {
            if($i == 0) {
                $sql .= "{$_GET['select']['columns'][$i]}";
            } else {
                $sql .= ", {$_GET['select']['columns'][$i]}";
            }
        }
        //{$_GET['select']['columns'][0]} 
        $sql .= " FROM {$_GET['from']['table']}";
        (isset($_GET['from']['as']) && ($_GET['from']['as']) !== "") ? $sql .= " AS {$_GET['from']['as']}" : $sql .= "";
        (isset($_GET['inner_join']['table']) && ($_GET['inner_join']['table']) !== "") ? $sql .= " INNER JOIN {$_GET['inner_join']['table']}" : $sql .= "";
        (isset($_GET['inner_join']['as']) && ($_GET['inner_join']['as']) !== "") ? $sql .= " AS {$_GET['inner_join']['as']}" : $sql .= "";
        if(isset($_GET['inner_join']['on']) && ($_GET['inner_join']['on']) !== "") {
            for($i = 0; $i < count($_GET['inner_join']['on']); $i++) {
                if($i == 0) {
                    $sql .= " ON {$_GET['inner_join']['on'][$i]}";
                } else {
                    $sql .= " AND {$_GET['inner_join']['on'][$i]}";
                }
            }
        }
        (isset($_GET['left_join']['table']) && ($_GET['left_join']['table']) !== "") ? $sql .= " LEFT JOIN {$_GET['left_join']['table']}" : $sql .= "";
        (isset($_GET['left_join']['as']) && ($_GET['left_join']['as']) !== "") ? $sql .= " AS {$_GET['left_join']['as']}" : $sql .= "";
        if(isset($_GET['left_join']['on']) && ($_GET['left_join']['on']) !== "") {
            for($i = 0; $i < count($_GET['left_join']['on']); $i++) {
                if($i == 0) {
                    $sql .= " ON {$_GET['left_join']['on'][$i]}";
                } else {
                    $sql .= " AND {$_GET['left_join']['on'][$i]}";
                }
            }
        }
        (isset($_GET['left_outer_join']['table']) && ($_GET['left_outer_join']['table']) !== "") ? $sql .= " LEFT OUTER JOIN {$_GET['left_outer_join']['table']}" : $sql .= "";
        (isset($_GET['left_outer_join']['as']) && ($_GET['left_outer_join']['as']) !== "") ? $sql .= " AS {$_GET['left_outer_join']['as']}" : $sql .= "";
        if(isset($_GET['left_outer_join']['on']) && ($_GET['left_outer_join']['on']) !== "") {
            for($i = 0; $i < count($_GET['left_outer_join']['on']); $i++) {
                if($i == 0) {
                    $sql .= " ON {$_GET['left_outer_join']['on'][$i]}";
                } else {
                    $sql .= " AND {$_GET['left_outer_join']['on'][$i]}";
                }
            }
        }
        (isset($_GET['where']) && ($_GET['where']) !== "") ? $sql .= " WHERE {$_GET['where']}" : $sql .= "";
        (isset($_GET['order_by']) && ($_GET['order_by']) !== "") ? $sql .= " ORDER BY {$_GET['order_by']}" : $sql .= ""; 
        (isset($_GET['direction']) && ($_GET['direction']) !== "") ? $sql .= " {$_GET['direction']}" : $sql .= "";
        (isset($_GET['limit']) && ($_GET['limit']) !== "") ? $sql .= " LIMIT {$_GET['limit']}" : $sql .= "";
        (isset($_GET['offset']) && ($_GET['offset']) !== "") ? $sql .= " OFFSET ".$_GET['offset'] * $_GET['limit']."" : $sql .= "";

        $statement = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute();

        // ------------------------------------------------
        // set the resulting array to associative
        $result = $statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $jsonArray = array();
        //$jsonArray["totalrecords"] = $total_records;
        $jsonArray["totalrecords"] = 1;
        while ( ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) !== false) {
            $jsonArray[] = $row;
        }
        // ------------------------------------------------
        $this->return($jsonArray);
        // ------------------------------------------------
    }

    private function return($jsonArray) {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($jsonArray);
    }

}

$query = new GET();

?>
```

OUTPUT:

```
string(56) "SELECT count(*) AS total_records FROM cb_cat WHERE :test"
object(PDOStatement)#3 (1) {
  ["queryString"]=>
  string(56) "SELECT count(*) AS total_records FROM cb_cat WHERE :test"
}
string(27) "systemgrp BETWEEN 10 AND 19"
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type boolean: &quot;systemgrp BETWEEN 10 AND 19&quot; ...
```

Comment: Is it because the :test contains a statement in itself and not just a variable...?

Comment: You can't parameterise an entire clause, only individual values. E.g. you could parameterise the 10 and the 19, but not the rest of it. Otherwise it wouldn't really protect against SQL injection. (Also elsewhere you're injecting user input directly into the queries anyway so the whole thing is a security disaster. If you're going to allow users to choose table names directly then - since those can't be parameterised either - you'll need to employ whitelisting to prevent any attempts to put unwanted text into that part of the query.)

Comment: Placeholders are only for values, not for full statements. Also, you're _wide open_ for SQL injection attacks. _Never_ use user data directly in your queries. Read [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) about prepared statements to learn how to actually use them.

Comment: I am using postgresql with a READ ONLY account.

Comment: ok. How is that relevant to any of the comments?

Comment: Would it still be possible for an injection attack then?

Comment: Yes of course. Injection is about changing the SQL statement to suit your own purposes beyond that the developer wanted you to be able to do. That could include selecting data you weren't supposed to have access to, just as much as inserting, updating or deleting things that you shouldn't. So simply being read-only doesn't fully protect you. (P.S. even if you are happy for people to read data from all the tables and rows you've created, you still don't want them to be able to read from the system tables such as information_schema, or run other queries to get system information.)

Comment: I understand, the read only account I am using only has access to the tables I consider to be fully accessible by the public. All the data in the tables this account has access too should be queried in any way the user wants. For Create, Update and Delete, I use only backend generated queries and a separate db account. With Postgresql I can give precise access to which tables or even columns are only readable.

Comment: you still wouldn't want people to be able to execute system information functions - have you restricted that? And access to SHOW commands?

Comment: This specific user account only has access to 3 tables with only the SELECT command.
Anyone should be able to make their own queries, some people want to make inner joins, other's just want a single datapoint, anything is possible.

Comment: And there are no restrictions on which rows people can view? e.g. it doesn't restrict you to data you created or only a certain team, or anything like that?

Comment: No, it is open source data from drill holes with their layer descriptions and also a table with C14 determinations, both with GPS coordinates. Anyone is allowed to query whatever they want from it. For example, all layers at a certain depth of a certain age at a certain location, etc. I can't possibly create every imaginable query beforehand. But having a read only account on these tables is an outcome.